# SendGrid Api won't send E-mail due to CORS protection

Tags: c#

I'm trying for hours to send an E-mail with using ASPNET WebApi 3.1 but it doesn't work at all. I got a StatusCode 401 Unauthorized due the CROSS ORIGIN (https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/cors/) so what I did was, hosted the API and the client (Aspnet Core MVC) on azure to make a request inside the server, but still, not working.!

This is how I did it.

```
public async Task<Response> SendEmail(string to, string name)
    {
        var services = ConfigureServices(new ServiceCollection()).BuildServiceProvider();
        var client = services.GetRequiredService<ISendGridClient>();

        var msg = new SendGridMessage()
        {
            From = new EmailAddress("a@outlook.com", "something something"),
            Subject = "AAAA AAAAAA"
        };

        msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(to, name));
        msg.SetTemplateId("d-00000000000000000000");
        msg.AddSubstitution("-user-", name);
        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return response;
        
    }
    private static IServiceCollection ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSendGrid(options =>
        {
            options.ApiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SENDGRID_API_KEY");
        });

        return services;
    }
```

And in the startup, I only allowed the client hosted.

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                              builder =>
                              {
                                  builder.WithOrigins("https://clientss2e.azurewebsites.net/");
                              });
        });
```

Comment: What happens if you create the client like `var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey)` instead of using `ConfigureServices` that will confirm if 401 is due to CORS or not passing the apiKey.

Comment: servers return CORS error when API is being called via AJAX, mostly from client side scripts such as JavaScript. You are calling API from C# code which runs from on server. Can you explain if you getting error in C# code or in the JavaScript code of the web page which is calling `SendEmail` ?

Comment: I'm using aspnet forms

Comment: @user1672994 I did, and I got the same response. The error comes from the C#, status code 401.